# Unknown network in Network Map

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, adsl-router

I have a ADSL Wireless Router (ZTE ZXV10 W300) connected to internet. My laptop is connected to the router via wireless network. When I check the Network Map (in Windows 7) it shows another wireless router and a computer (which I do not own) and Routers are connected through an Unknown device.

[image]

*Green box shows the part I can identify*

I guessed this router is somewhere in my neighbourhood, so to disconnect it I restarted my router and even changed the wireless network shared key, but it keeps showing in my network map..

Note: I tried to ping the Unknown pc IP, but it can not be reachable.

Is the routers really connected each other? how to disconnect this unknown network from my network?

Answer (score 1):

With that router. Yes, it looks like someone has hacked your wireless encryption. This can easily be done if your router has WPS enabled (can be hacked , repeatedly giving out your wpa2 passwords) or if your using WPA1 (can be hacked with rainbow tables) or WEP encryption, which can be hacked in a matter of seconds.

Try these steps, 
1. Factory reset the modem/router
(This step is important, your hacker may already have remote administration enabled)

2. Set initial admin password in the configuration (make it strong)

3.disable wps if possible in the configuration 
(replace the modem if you can't, WPS is broken)

4. Set a custom WPA2 psk password.
   (16 digit alpha-numerical with uppercase and special characters)

That should solve it if it's a neighborhood kid with Kali Linux and a WiFi amp.

Answer (score 0):

Is the IP a private IP address?

It's common for ISPs to break the rules and use public IP addresses with their public infrastructure to shape traffic, among other reasons, and they're starting do it in such a way that it doesn't interfere with NAT.

To view this, you can pathping from your affected network to some machine across town (work to home for exmaple) and wait a little bit for the results. What you'll see first are the private, inside-local IP addresses for your inside network of wherever you are, then a public IP address letting you know that your traffic made it outside, then a private IP address denoting your ISP using their traffic-shaping route that I mentioned, then back to public addresses until you get to your target's outside global address.

Screenshot the results here if you're unsure about how to interpret them.

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the Channel your wifi router uses because both routers may be overlapping

Comment: You are confusing physical layer noise with message integrity.  Information at that level would not be affected by overlapping WiFi channels.